# What is the status of jQuery's multi-argument content syntax: deprecated, supported, documented?

Tags: jquery

I've never seen this in any jQuery docs I've read; nor, have I ever seen it in the wild. I just observed multi-content syntax working here for the `after` modifier with jQuery 1.4.2. Is this supported syntax? Is it deprecated?

```
$(".section.warranty .warranty_checks :last").after(
  $('<div class="little check" />').click( function () {
      alert('hi')                                       
  } )                                                   
  , $('<span>OEM</span>')  /*Notice this (a second) argument */    
);
```

Here is the signature for after:  `.after( content )`. But, as my example shows it should be `.after( content [, content...] )`

I've never seen any indication in the jQuery grammar that any of the functions accept more than one argument (content) in such a fashion.

**UPDATE**: What did it do? I left this out thinking it was obvious:

It inserts a `<div class="little check" />` with the aforementioned callback on `.click()` and follows it up with a totally new sibling element `<span>OEM</span>`.

See [this follow-up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932796/how-do-i-rewrite-after-content-content) for a question about how to rewrite this.

Comment: Worked, actually, the weird thing was this was the *only* way I could get it to work. In inserts the `<div>` with the working callback, followed by the `<span>` with the word `OEM` as content.

Answer (score 2):

Yes this *works*, though it's not technically supported, [you can see a demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/Wqhd4/).

If you give [`.after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) multiple arguments, it'll append them one at a time.

You can see the relevant jQuery core code here: http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/manipulation.js#L141

It takes all the arguments provided and pushes them on the stack for insertion...but since this isn't a documented feature, it may change in any future jQuery release (though it appears safe for at least 1.4.3).

Comment: Note that if the jQuery object has no elements, it will only use the first parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the corroboration and jsfiddle is new to me and pretty cool. Thanks for the link.

Comment: @SLaks - good point, though it would have no effect with no elements anyway :)

Comment: Look at the source. It does do something. `else if ( arguments.length )`

Comment: @Slaks - Ah yeah, I thought you meant the set you're running the `.after()` on being empty

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/after/) it is not allowed, but you see in the code that it is possible (what you however already know from your experiments ;-) )

```
after: function() {
    if ( this[0] && this[0].parentNode ) {
        return this.domManip(arguments, false, function( elem ) {
            this.parentNode.insertBefore( elem, this.nextSibling );
        });
    } else if ( arguments.length ) {
        var set = this.pushStack( this, "after", arguments );
        set.push.apply( set, jQuery(arguments[0]).toArray() );
        return set;
    }
},
```

Comment: I would say it *works*, supported is a very different term :) anything not in documentation is fair game for changing

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: I thought that the parameter was being passed to `click`.
This answer is correct but irrelevant.

<strike>These functions only take one parameter.

Any other parameters will be ignored (for now).</strike>

Therefore, the second parameter in your example is ignored.
However, if jQuery ever adds an optional parameter to these functions (eg, a boolean to add a live handler), your example will stop working.

The handlers are defined by jQuery (1.4.2) like this:

```
jQuery.each( ("blur focus focusin focusout load resize scroll unload click dblclick " +
    "mousedown mouseup mousemove mouseover mouseout mouseenter mouseleave " +
    "change select submit keydown keypress keyup error").split(" "), function( i, name ) {

    // Handle event binding
    jQuery.fn[ name ] = function( fn ) {
        return fn ? this.bind( name, fn ) : this.trigger( name );
    };

    if ( jQuery.attrFn ) {
        jQuery.attrFn[ name ] = true;
    }
});
```

This code loops through the event names and creates the following function for each event:

```
    jQuery.fn[ name ] = function( fn ) {
        return fn ? this.bind( name, fn ) : this.trigger( name );
    };
```

As you can see, the function only uses one parameter.

Comment: It's not the `click` that is passed two arguments, it's the `after`.