# jQuery: How do I rewrite .after( content, content )?

Tags: jquery

I've got this form working, but according to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932549/what-is-the-status-of-jquerys-multi-argument-content-syntax-deprecated-support) it might not be supported: it isn't in the docs either way -- but the intention is pretty obvious in the code.

```
$(".section.warranty .warranty_checks :last").after(
  $('<div class="little check" />').click( function () {
      alert('hi')
  } )
  , $('<span>OEM</span>')  /*Notice this (a second) argument */
);
```

What this does is insert `<div class="little check">` with a simple `.click()` callback, followed by a sibling of `<span>OEM</span>`. How else can I write this then? I'm having difficulty conjuring something working by chaining any combination of `.after()`, and `.insertAfter()`?

I would expect this to work, but it doesn't:

```
$(".section.warranty .warranty_checks :last").after(
  $('<div class="little check" />').click( function () {
      alert('hi')
  } ).after ( $('<span>OEM</span>')  )
);
```

I would also expect this to work, but it doesn't:

```
$(".section.warranty .warranty_checks :last").after(
  $('<span>OEM</span>').insertAfter(
    $('<div class="little check" />').click( function () {
       alert('hi')
    } )
  );
);
```

-> **Please see [my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U2WjX/) for examples (test case)**

Comment: I don't think you need to insert click event along with div, you need to insert just div then using jquery live(), you can call the click event on newly created element, I'm sorry if that is not what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be the naive answer:

```
$(".section.warranty .warranty_checks :last").after(
    $('<span>OEM</span>')
).after(
    $('<div class="little check" />').click( function () {
     alert('hi')
    }
);
```

Seems to work...

**EDIT**: have I missed the point here?  http://jsfiddle.net/wFx9Z/

Comment: I see what is happening, you're doing `$(...).after().after()`, I'm doing `$(...).after( $().after() )`, and mine isn't working because it is not in the document yet. Nifty.

Answer (score 0):

Well your code works for me if I change it to

```
$(".section.warranty .warranty_checks :last").after(
  $('<div class="little check"></div>').click( function () {
    alert('hi')
  } )
  , $('<span>OEM</span>')  /*Notice this (a second) argument */
);
```

Notice the `<div class="little check"></div>`. What does `<div class="little check" />` do anyway?

Comment: notice what `.`? That is still `.after( content, content )`, which is what I'm trying to avoid because it is not said to be supported.

Comment: `<div class="little check" />` is an empty styled element ``.little.check { width:3em; height:3em; border:1px solid black; ... }` with an event on `.click()`. And, this is still `.after( content, content )`. Please read the [referenced post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932549/what-is-the-status-of-jquerys-multi-argument-content-syntax-deprecated-support).